# Neural Network classifier in python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Here I developed a neural network classifier to solve the titanic problem.

```
from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer

nn = Classifier(
    layers=[
        Layer("Maxout", units=100, pieces=2),
        Layer("Softmax")],
    learning_rate=0.001,
    n_iter=25)


nn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I got this error, I have tried a lot to fix it but nothing works with me.
Please, help me

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pieces'

Comment: This could have been easily solved by looking at the possible parameters for Layer()

Answer (score 0):

The signature of [`Layer`](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_mlp.html#layer-specifications) does not define any argument called `pieces`. To create two layers with same parameters, you'll have to define the `Layer` object twice:

```
layers=[
    Layer("Sigmoid", units=100),
    Layer("Sigmoid", units=100),
    Layer("Softmax",  units=1)] # The units parameter is not optional
```

More so, `"Maxout"` does not look like a `Layer` type. Not sure of where you found that.

> Specifically, options are `Rectifier`, `Sigmoid`, `Tanh`, and `ExpLin`
>   for non-linear layers and `Linear` or `Softmax` for output layers

Comment: I found it here https://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_model.html#classification

Comment: I have tried what you suggest but there is an error, AssertionError: Mismatch between dataset size and units in output layer.